# Instead of npm is there any disadvantages using old-school <script> tags?

Tags: npm, web-applications, frontend

Recently, node package manager is very popular and doing a lot of job for us, however it is really difficult to understand what is going on under the hood. I really like simple  tags to insert Vue, Babel etc. Haven't worked on big projects, I really wonder is there any disadvantages using script tags over npm-cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you npm install a library, plugin, extension, etc it can be declared as a dependency with a --save flag. In doing so it is marked as a dependency in your package.json file, which is key to version control for your dependencies. If you just use the CDN you are pulling in a path to a library that may be deprecated at some point in the future.

During development it is ok to use CDNs, but in production it is not good practice for dependencies (though I do it for certain exceptions, such as a google font).

Comment: Is there a way to understand what is going on while typing such as npm update, npm install package as far as I see official website doesn't tell about that much.

Comment: When you update your npm-installed packages will update to the most current version permitted in your package.json file. Please see this portion of the NPM documentation regarding this functionality https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies